# Setting priority in order of paths with react-router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

My routing looks like this

```
<Route path="account" component={Page1}>
    <Route path="new" component={Page2}/>  
    <Route path="(:userId)" component={Page1}/>
</Route>
```

Whenever I go to `account/new` it defaults to the `(:userId)` path and directs me to `Page1` treating 'new' as the optional parameter. How can I make it default to `Page2`?

I am using V3 of `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

It is going to `Page1` because account needs to be an exact path. Since it isn't, when you go to `account/new` it will show the component for `account`. Try this:

```
<Route exact path="/account" component={Page1}>
    <Route path="/new" component={Page2}/>  
    <Route path="/(:userId)" component={Page1}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is not doing the trick. Why did you add the "/" to every path?

Comment: Out of habit/consistency

Comment: gotcha, was just curious. Yeah - I added exact in there but it still takes me to Page1 :/

Comment: Have you tried adding the leading slashes? I have read in the documentation that it’s proper formatting, could be giving you the unexpected results.

Comment: I have, in fact, when I do everything breaks, it will add 2 slashes like `//account//new`. I can also confirm that the issue is the first path `/account` and not the other one `(:userId)` , just like you said.

Comment: What type of router are you using (browser, hash, etc) and do you have a basename set at all?

Comment: Kate I don't think V3 supports the `exact` prop. I think that's the issue here. Seems like `IndexRoute` is the replacement?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using v3? What version of React are you using?

Comment: React version is 15.6.2, react-router is 3.2.1. The reason is that switching to react-router V4 would break a few things and it's a pretty large codebase.

Comment: It seems to have to to with `props.children`, check out this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/01L5ae3m/45/